# i m sending json data and try to get in struts2 action class

Tags: jquery, struts2

my json data is

{"postData":[{"itemId":"mcw750","currentQty":"90","saleQty":"8","unitPrice":"100","salePrice":"800"}]}

```
var postData = JSON.stringify(data);

alert("The following data are sending to the server:\n"+postData);\\here i m getting all values..

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7001/Final_Subgrid2/jsonaction.action",
    dataType:"JSON",
    data:postData,
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
    alert("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error");
    }
});
```

In Action class i have public List postData with setter and getter.
Please tell me why i m getting null data in action class.

i have Employee pojo class.(itemId,currentQty,saleQty,unitPrice,totalPrice)
when i m sending updated jqgrid data to action class its getting null values..
my json data is okay and ajax is sending proper data to action(as seen in firebug)

my action mapping is .

still   I m  getting null values please guide me in proper direction

At last I have solved my problem ..thanks to all for helping me ..

Comment: Probably because you're not using the JSON plugin, but who knows; you don't say.

Comment: i m using struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.jar ..

Comment: I have checked its working properly but still i m not getting data in action class .please tell me .

Comment: I have also checked in firebug .my ajax sending proper data but my action class response is null

Comment: Then you need to provide more information. The easiest would be an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) hosted on something like github.

Comment: my struts mapping is <action name="jsonaction" class="main.com.java.action.GetData" method="getJson">
       
           <result type="json"/>

    </action>

Comment: in my action class I have public list(Employee) postData and getter and setter.

Comment: You are sending an array of objects, each with a single property, not an array of objects, each being an employee.

Comment: i m sending array of objects, each being an employee.

Comment: i have used this data to load jqgrid List<Employee> users = new ArrayList<Employee>();
              
                 Employee user1 = new Employee();
                 user1.setItemId("mcb250");
                 user1.setCurrentQty(100);
                 user1.setSaleQty(10);
                 user1.setUnitPrice(100);  and i m sending this data to server after modifiy the grid

Comment: No you're not, the data you show is an array of objects, each with a single property. The first element is a single object with the property `itemId`, the second element is a single object with the property `currentQty`, etc. Perhaps you have posted the incorrect code.

Comment: sorry i m new in struts and ajax ..but i want to send this data to server  {"postData":[{"itemId":"mcw750","currentQty":"90","saleQty":"8","unitPrice":"100","salePrice":"800"}]} (this is my actual data ) please guide me ..thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the correct, current information-what you just wrote is not what's in your question. Also, ` Employee` seems like a **horrible** class name for what is clearly an invoice line item.

Comment: ok I have Employee pojo class  which have,  private String ItemId;
  private Integer  CurrentQty;
  private Integer  SaleQty;
  private Integer UnitPrice;
  private Integer SalePrice;    and i have jqgrid data  (as mentioned above) and want to send to server to store in database .

Comment: And what's the problem? As I said: edit your question to be accurate, otherwise there's no point in further discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my struts.xml and its works..

```
<action name="jsonaction" class="main.com.java.action.GetData" method="getJson">
  <interceptor-ref name="json">
    <param name="contentType">application/JSON</param>
    <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
  </interceptor-ref>

  <result name="success" type="json"/>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a getter/setter for postdata, the postdata items are being individually sent as request params, so itemId is in the requestmap as itemId. 
Postdata is not being sent as json.

Add getters/setters in your action class for all the items you are sending in your postdata

[get/set]ItemId, [get/set]CurrentQty, ....

Comment: i have added get/set for all the items but i m getting that values null in actions class still..please guide me ..

Comment: .should i have to deserializee json data in action class.I have seen on internet that we have to deserialize json data in action class.i m confused..

Comment: i m getting eclipse console output like  Executing action method = getJson
Json DataRetrieve Data==nullJson DataRetrieve Data==null00:30:13,086 DEBUG JSONUtil:68 - [JSON]{"currentQty":null,"itemId":null,"json":"success","salePrice":null,"saleQty":null,"sentData":{},"unitPrice":null}

Comment: I have modified my struts.xml and its works..<action name="jsonaction" class="main.com.java.action.GetData" method="getJson">
       <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/JSON</param>
           
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param> 
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="json"/>
    </action>